# How do I determine what file is missing from the g++ compiler error?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, g++

I'm trying to compile some code (not mine) and I run into errors. I have a couple questions:

1) Obviously, how do I fix my error, and

2a) I suspect that I need to install a Qt library/package or something or other but I just can't seem to figure out what I need to do. How do I determine what it is that I am actually missing, and

2b) where I can install it? (how best to use apt-file, locate, something else maybe?)

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, 64bit and g++4.6.3

```
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/include/Inventor/annex -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/share/qt4/include -I/usr/share/qt4/include/Qt  -I/usr/local/include/Inventor/annex -D_REENTRANT  -I/home/mishkin/mincinstall/include   -g -O2 -MT brain-view.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/brain-view.Tpo" -c -o brain-view.o brain-view.cc; \
    then mv -f ".deps/brain-view.Tpo" ".deps/brain-view.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/brain-view.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
In file included from brainApp.h:80:0,
                 from callbacks.h:7,
                 from brain-view.cc:52:
vertstatsForm.h:12:14: fatal error: Qt: No such file or directory
```

I looked inside vertstatsForm.h:12:14 and the 12 line is #include < Qt >

```
#ifndef VERTSTATSFORM_H
#define VERTSTATSFORM_H

#include <Qt>  <-----line 12
#include <qvariant.h>
#include <qdialog.h>
#include <Qt3Support/Q3GridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
```

Comment: You need to install Qt4. Look it up on a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question 2, if the error message is

```
fatal error: QXXXX: No such file or directory
```

Do this

```
locate QXXXX
```

which will give you something like this

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QXXXX
```

which means you should replace

```
#include <QXXXX>
```

with

```
#include <QtGui/QXXXX>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer question 1, try to remove

```
#include <Qt>
```

If it still is not working, replace it with

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
```

and/or other modules that you might need.

Comment: That solved the first problem, and I had to fix lots of other modules.  Unfortunately that still gave me errors like this `In file included from Rinterface.h:5:0, from brainApp.h:11, from callbacks.h:7, from brain-view.cc:53: /usr/share/qt4/include/Qt3Support/q3socket.h:82:54: error: ‘Q_UINT16’ has not been declared` It looks like this project was coded with Qt3 and I have Qt4 on my system. Not sure what to do.